# How to add element in a list in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```js
function prepend(element, liste) {
  let tab = [];
  
  for (let node = list; node; node = node.rest){
    tab.push(node.value);
  }
  
  tab.unshift(element);
  
  let history = " ";
      
  for(let elt of tab) {
   if( array.indexOf(elt) === array.length - 1) {
     
     history += "{value :" + elt +"}";
   }
     history += "{value :" + elt +", rest :";
   
  }
  
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length -1; i++) {
    history += "}";
  }
    
  return history;
}


console.log(prepend(8, {value :1, rest :{value :2, rest :{value :3, rest :{value :4, rest : null}}}}));
```

I try to add value to this array but it did not work
when trying to add 8 to the list, I convert it first by creating an array then i convert it back to list
but it returns an error

Comment: `prepend = (element, list) => ({value: element, rest: list})` - no need for the gymnastics with converting to array and back.

Comment: can you share samples for element and list

Comment: @kingneo the last line of the code.

Comment: Thanks you guys especially to VLAZ

Comment: [object Object] {
  rest: [object Object] {
    rest: [object Object] { ... },
    value: 1
  },
  value: 8 here is what codepen return VLAZ

Comment: But do think my approach can work?

Comment: Don't you need an object as a result? If you need JSON, then just encode it: `prepend = (element, list) => JSON.stringify({value: element, rest: list}) `

Comment: Thanks VLAZ i did not realize that